# Output of the c program

Tags: c++

When running the following code, the output is 2 4 6. I expected it to be 2 5 and so on... 
**Why the difference?**

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main() {
     static int i;
     for (i++; ++i; i++) {
     printf("%d ", i);
     if (i == 6)
         break;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

---

I did the same thing here, without the `for` loop, from 2nd iteration. The result is 5.
**Why is that?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    static int i=2;
    i++;
    i++;
    cout<<++i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'please explain the flow' no thanks.  Why don't you take all those pre-post increments out of the for loop and place them is such a manner that the code is easy to follow?    As above, such code is terribru and not a good example to future SO users/visitors.

Comment: yes i'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see the syntax of for loop which is

```
for(initialize;condition;inc/decrement)
```

The statement in initialize block only executes once at the starting of for loop that's why it is incrementing `i` by 2.

Hopefully that help

Answer (score 2):

Each time the loop is traversed you increase `i` by two, not three (I guess you expected the latter to happen).

In a general case

```
for ( init_statement ; condition ; iteration_expression ) {
    loop_statements
}
```

is equivalent to

```
init_statement
for ( ; condition ; ) {
    loop_statements
    iteration_expression
}
```

and

```
init_statement
while ( condition ) {
    loop_statements
    iteration_expression
}
```

See, e.g., [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for).

In your case,

```
for (i++; ++i; i++) {
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
i++
for ( ; ++i; ) {
    ...
    i++
}
```

and

```
i++
while ( ++i ) {
    ...
    i++ ;
}
```

---

As for your second piece of code, you mention that "The result is 5". It appears you expect otherwise, perhaps 4. If so, try replacing

```
cout<<++i;
```

with

```
cout<<i++;
```

(incrementing prior vs. after other operations in the sentence).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: variables with `static` storage are zero-initialised.

Answer (score 0):

In a `for` loop you've got 4 parts. I forget the "official" name for the individual pieces but I typically refer to them as:

1. Initialization
2. Anchor Statement
3. Body
4. Follow-up

effectively:

```
for(Initialization (1); Anchor Statement (2); Follow-up (4))
{
    Body (3)
}
```

It's going to hit in the following order:

1, 2, 3, 4, [2, 3, 4]... until step 2 evaluates to `false` or a `break` statement is hit. Then it exits.

So `i` starts as `0`.
You hit step 1 and 2, making `i` evaluate to `2` in step 3 (the body).

Then you hit step 4 and 2, making `i` evaluate to 4 in step 3.

Then you hit step 4 and 2, making `i` evaluate to 6 in step 3.

Then you have a `break` statement that will exit the loop.

The important part that seems to be the confusion, is that the initialization step only runs once.